# Jenkins CodeCommit integration on AWS EC2 with role

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I host Jenkins on my Linux EC2, I wanted to know if it's possible to get access to CodeCommit only with EC2 Role, without IAM User, or SSH keys?

What I expect is to create some role that has access to CodeCommit repository and I can just create projects where I pass my repository link and that's all